# FileNotFound exception, when files are in /Applications/Foobar.app on a Mac

Tags: java

**Summary** - this code:

```
File f = new File("dbFile.dat");
f.getAbsolutePath();
```

Returns:

```
/Applications/dbFile.dat
```

The problem is that my application's resources (3d party jars for instance) are located in "Applications/Foobar.app/...".

**How to get the path to my install folder without hardcoding anything?**

**Details**:

I'm using a 3d party library for which I need to provide a filename:

```
ls = new LookupService("dbFile.dat");
```

When distributed, this file is placed in the root of my install folder, next to the executable files - works great on Windows.

However, on Mac I get a FNF exception because the library isn't searching in the correct location:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: dbFile.dat (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
...
```

Comment: Is the file a resource file that is packaged and deployed together with your application? Then you should use a class loader for loading it.

Comment: I can't do that. The library I'm using only accepts a String parameter which it then uses to access the file.

Comment: Maybe your are looking for: File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "dbFile.dat"); ? Of course, the current working directory must be correctly set at startup time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the *"foobar.app/.../dbFile.dat"* part of the *"/Applications/foobar.app/.../dbFile.dat"* path is defined in an Ant build file and therefore probably not subject to change by the user at install time as I originally thought, so I used:

```
String pathToUse = PlatformDetector.IsMacOS() ? "/Applications/foobar.app/.../dbFile.dat" : "dbFile.dat";
```

Comment: The string "Applications" may be localized.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this and post back - everything's ok. The strings are translated, but the path is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
URL myClass = MyClass.class.getResource("MyClass.class");
System.out.println(myClass.getPath());
```

This will print out something like this:

```
file:/home/mike/test.jar!/MyClass.class
```

You can parse out what you need from that.